# A relation of the lengths of line segments in a circumscribed star pentagon.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, projective-geometry, polygons

A few days ago I posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243653/better-method-to-solve-a-geometric-problem) and timon92 gave a beautiful solution. Using timon92's method, one can easily show that $ER\cdot BS\cdot CD=DE\cdot RS\cdot BC$ (as with the notations in the figure below). I applied this fact five times and derived the following result.

> Let $ABCDE$ be a circumscribed pentagon. $BD$ and $CE$ meet at $P$. $AD$ and $CE$ meet at $Q$. $AD$ and $BE$ meet at $R$. $AC$ and $BE$ meet at $S$. $AC$ and $BD$ meet at $T$. Let $p_1$ be the product of the lengths of the five sides of the pentagon $ABCDE$, $p_2$ be the product of the lengths of the five sides of the pentagon $PQRST$ and $p_3$ be the product of the lengths of the tens sides of the star-shaped decagon $ASBTCPDQER$. Then we have $p_1p_2=p_3$.

The product of the lengths of the red line segments is equal to the product of the lengths of the blue line segments.

[image: The product of red line segments equals the product of blue line segments]

My questions:

(1) Are there any other proofs of this result?

(2) Are there any similar results for other star polygons?

Comment: Also, the law of sines kills it.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I see it now. Just applying $10$ times. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! And... thank you for your nice problem!

Comment: There is a possibility to get an area of $ABCDE$ by given areas of $\Delta ABC,$ $\Delta BCD$, $\Delta CDE$, $\Delta DEA$ and $\Delta EAB.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a central projection with a center $A$  from the line $AB$ to the circle.

We see that $p(E)=E$, $p(R)=D$, $p(S)=C$ and $p(B)=B$.

We know that a сross-ratio of $E,$ $S$, $R$ and $B$ on the line $EB$ is equal to the cross-ratio of $E$, $C$, $D$ and $B$ on the circle.

Id est,
$$\frac{ER}{EB}:\frac{SR}{SB}=\frac{ED}{EB}:\frac{CD}{CB}$$ or
$$\frac{ER\cdot SB}{SR}=\frac{ED\cdot BC}{CD}$$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the original competition problem is a direct application of the invariance of cross-ratio.

Comment: @CY Aries Maybe. Just sometimes the projective geometry gives a solution immediately.