# Calculate missing side of quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

This is a problem from a Geometry Facebook group. Segment $AB$ is split as shown in the picture, in sub-segments of length 2, 5 and 4. Also $BT=2$ and $AS=5$. A, B, T and S are on the same circle. Also by extending TQ and SP, they intersect on point C, which supposedly is also on the same circle. We are looking for length of ST.

I have tried it in Geogebra and there is no way to have C on the same circle. I suspect something is wrong.

Since $ABTS$ is cyclic, I have tried to use several of its properties, for example, to draw its diagonals $d_1$ and $d_2$ (not shown in the image) and then use the property $d_1*d_2 = 11x+5$ but I am not getting anywhere.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: The figure can be constructed (just checked with GeoGebra) and $X\approx6.25$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca how? I have tried moving S and T on their circles but C is always outside the big circle.

Comment: Construct the circle through $A$ and $B$, having its center on a generic point $O$ on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$. Construct then $S$ and $T$ on that circle and move $O$ until the intersection $C$ lies on the same circle.

Comment: I tried it but there is no way the circle passes through all 3 points (S, T and C). Remember that lines CS and CT must pass through P and Q, where $BQ=4$ and $AP=2$.

Comment: Here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzxmC.png

Comment: I see. I now tried again and got a similar measurement from Geogebra, but I still don't know how to compute it by using geometry, or even trigonometry. Thank you.

Comment: There several similar triangles and you can create more. For example you could find AC to be 7/2... and on

Comment: @Moti AC is not $7/2$. What similar triangles are you referring to?

Comment: @Juan It is. BTQ is similar ACQ

Answer (score 1):

With

$$
\cases{
r_1=2\\
r_2 = 5\\
d_{BQ} = 4\\
d_{QP} = 5\\
d_{PA} = 2\\
\vec h = (0,1)\\
O=(0,0)\\
T=(t_x,t_y)\\
S=(s_x,s_y)\\
p = (x,y)\\
B=r(-\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\\
A=r(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\\
Q=B+d_{BQ}\vec h\\
P=A-d_{PA}\vec h\\
L_1\to p = T+\lambda(Q-T)\\
L_2\to p = S+\mu(P-S)\\
C = L_1\cap L_2\\
(A-B)\cdot(A-B) = (d_{BQ}+d_{QP}+d_{PA})^2\\
(B-T)\cdot(B-T) = r_1^2\\
(A-S)\cdot(A-S) = r_2^2\\
(T-O)\cdot(T-O) = r^2\\
(S-O)\cdot(S-O) = r^2\\
(C-O)\cdot(C-O) = r^2
}
$$

and solving the last six equations for $r,s_x,s_y,t_x,t_y,\theta$ we obtain

$$
\cases{
r=6.09126\\
s_x =1.6875\\
s_y =5.85284\\
t_x =-4.35563\\
t_y = 4.25815\\
\theta = 0.444249
}
$$

and also $X = [TS] = \frac{25}{4}$

[image]

NOTE

Latter I saw the beautiful answer from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243653/better-method-to-solve-a-geometric-problem)